# Make the whole page scalable

Tags: html, css, web

I have a quick project that I'm building right now. That's why I would like to make my whole page scalable and not use media queries, as it would be faster and save me a lot of time. The only problem is that I'm still a beginner, and I don't really know how to make it fully scalable.

Could someone help me with this? As you can see, the page is not really optimized, the nav bar doesn't resize, and the links don't either (properly, at least). Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Thermocase</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img/fav.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <img src="img/iphone.png" class="bg" />
  <nav class="global-nav">
    <img src="img/thermocase.png" class="logo-left" />
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Product</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: bebas;
    src: url(font/coyote.ttf);
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein { /* Opera */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes load_up {
    from {
        opacity:0;top:10%
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;top:0%;
    }

}

@-webkit-keyframes load_up {
    from {
        opacity:0;top:10%
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;top:0%;
    }

}

@-moz-keyframes load_up{
    from {
        opacity:0;top:10%
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;top:0%;
    }

}

@-o-keyframes load_up{
    from {
        opacity:0;top:10%
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;top:0%;
    }

}



body {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.bg {
    animation: fadein 4s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 4s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: fadein 4s; /* Opera */
    animation: load_up 2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: load_up 2s forwards;
    -moz-animation: load_up 2s forwards;
    -o-animation : load_up 2s forwards;
    width: 45%;
    left: 28%;
    padding-top: 7%;
    position: fixed;
}

.global-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffff;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.logo-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 27%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    display: block;
    width: 15%;


}


.menu li { 
    display: block;
    font-family: bebas;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color:#CF2034;
    transition: color .7s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
    -o-transition: color .7s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
    -moz-transition: color .7s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
    -webkit-transition: color .7s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1);
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;

}

.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit; 
    color: black;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;


}

.menu a:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #CF2034;
    content: "";
    transform: scale(0);
    -o-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1) ;
    -moz-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1) ;
    -webkit-transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1) ;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.11, 0.7, 0, 1) ;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;

}

.menu a:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: what have you tried already? Why didn't it work? Have you read the specs from **W3C** or **MDN** ?

Comment: @Martin if you manage to try out my page, you will see that the nav bar doesn't resize, and neither the links do.

Comment: Edit your question and add this detail.

Comment: You probably want `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your HTML code.

Comment: Define "scalable". What specific behaviour do you want that you don't get now?

Comment: That all elements on the page stay at the same ratio as the tab gets smaller

Answer (score 2):

here are a few tips.

### Use relative dimensions

You could do so thanks to various units:

- **percentages**
- **em**: relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)
- **ex**: relative to the x-height of the current font (rarely used)
- **ch**: relative to width of the "0" (zero)
- **rem**: relative to font-size of the root element
- **vw** and **vh**: relative to 1% of the width **or** the height of the viewport
- **vmin** and **vmax**: relative to 1% of viewport's* smaller **or** larger dimension
- *and many more...*

> https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_units.asp
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

You may also want to check **browser's support** before using such units:

1. [Viewport's units support tables](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

### Correctly set the viewport

*allowing smaller screens to zoom in and out*

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
```

> A  viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.
>
> The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).
>
> The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.
> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

### Serve different pages based on the device

[Dynamic serving - Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/dynamic-serving)

I never used this technique, so I hope you'll find all you need in the Web Fundamentals.

### Use media-queries

*I know you don't want to, but it's the best options you've got*

Here are some references:

- [Using media queries - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
- [Responsive Web Design - Media Queries - W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
- [CSS3 @media Rule - W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

---

Hope I helped a bit :)

Comment: Thanks for the huge help. Much apprecieted :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a media query in your CSS, which would also include classes and IDs with percentages.